# Am trying to get a simple program that will work out and state if a user is the same age, older or younger but I can't get it to work properly

Tags: python

Am trying to get a simple program that will work out and state if a user is the same age, older or younger but I can't get it to work properly. Where am I going wrong please?

```
print('Hello! I am your faithful computer!')
Person=input('Whats your name?')
print('Hello,', Person)
Age = (input('How old are you?'))

if Age == '9':
    print ('We are the same age!')
    
elif Age < '9':
    print ('You are younger than me')

else Age > '9':
    print ('You are older than me')
```

Comment: You should convert the string returned by `input()` into an `int` first, then compare your `Age` variable to integers. ie: `Age = int(input('How old are you?')); if Age == 9:` etc.

Comment: There's no condition in `else:`. By definition the condition is when all the previous conditions are false.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    print('Hello! I am your faithful computer!')
    Person=input('Whats your name?')
    print('Hello,', Person)

    # your input now is an integer
    Age = (int(input('How old are you?'))) 

    # all comparisons must be between numbers
    if Age == 9: 
        print ('We are the same age!')
        
    elif Age < 9:
        print ('You are younger than me')

    elif Age > 9:
        print ('You are older than me')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the input as text, and you can't use > nor < with text.

To fix it you need to convert the variable Age to integer.

Comment: You can use `>` and `<`, but you won't get the expected result in this case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).